# merge listing of foldersfrom 2 directories - c#

Tags: c#

Need to display folder listings from 2 different network shares. What is the best way to merge them? This is a legacy c# code...

The merged list is displayed in a list view control

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FileInfo[] f = new DirectoryInfo(@"/folder1").GetFiles()
    .Union(new DirectoryInfo(@"/folder1").GetDirectories())
    .Union(new DirectoryInfo(@"/folder2").GetFiles())
    .Union(new DirectoryInfo(@"/folder2").GetDirectories()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, don't know if it is. Didn't realise you meant framework 1.1 by "legacy code"